# Yii2 remove unique validator

Tags: yii2

I have an AR model, it has the following rules:

```
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['category_id', 'source', 'url', 'title', 'thumbs', 'duration', 'status', 'created_at'], 'required'],
            [['category_id', 'status', 'views', 'ratings', 'created_at'], 'integer'],
            [['rating'], 'double'],
            [['source', 'url', 'title', 'slug'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['url'], 'unique', 'on' => 'create'],
            [['category_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Category::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['category_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

I want to do a soft delete so I have the following.

```
    /**
     * Deletes an existing Video model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $model->status = 0;
        //var_dump($model->validate());
        //var_dump($model->getErrors());die;
        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

But unfortunately I cannot change the status of model, because the validation says that (The url xxxxxxx has been taken) so I went to the PostgreSql, and I checked the records, but unfortunately only the updating record has this value! So in my mind the Yii2 unique validatios is bad. I would like to remove the unique validator, but it seems it is impossible. Because I commented out the uniqure row in the rule array, but it did not help me. I restarted the machine, but I do not know, it seems Yii2 want always check the url is unique or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scenario

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['soft_delete'] = ['status',]; //Scenario Values Only Accepted
    return $scenarios;
}



public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->status = 0;
    $model->scenario = 'soft_delete';
    //var_dump($model->validate());
    //var_dump($model->getErrors());die;
    $model->save();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

or another way is suppress validation for this action

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->status = 0;
    //var_dump($model->validate());
    //var_dump($model->getErrors());die;
    $model->save(false);

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```